# Ruby - encrypted_strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, encryption

A bit of a Ruby newbie here - should be an easy question:
I want to use the encrypted_strings gem to create a password encrypted string: 
(from http://rdoc.info/projects/pluginaweek/encrypted_strings)

Question is: Everything works fine, but **how come I don't need the password to decrypt the string?** Say I want to store the string somewhere for a while,like the session. Is the password also stored with it? (which would seem very strange?). And no, I'm not planning on using 'secret-key' or any similar hack as a password.

I am planning on dynamically generating a class variable @@password using a uuid, which I don't store other than in memory, and can change from one running of the program to the next.

Symmetric:

```
>> password = 'shhhh'
 => "shhhh"
 >> crypted_password = password.encrypt(:symmetric, :password => 'secret_key')
 => "qSg8vOo6QfU=\n"
  >> crypted_password.class
 => String
 >> crypted_password == 'shhhh'
 => true
 >> password = crypted_password.decrypt
 => "shhhh"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a *symmetric* encryption scheme, you only need the same password for encryption and decryption.  And from the looks of it, the password is stored in an instance variable on the encrypted string:

```
>> secret = '123'
=> "123"
>> crypted = secret.encrypt(:symmetric, :password => "password")
=> "R5RVA511Nzw=\n"
>> crypted.instance_variables
=> ["@cipher"]
>> crypted.instance_variable_get("@cipher")
=> #<EncryptedStrings::SymmetricCipher:0x101192768 @password="password", @algorithm="DES-EDE3-CBC">
```

So yes, if you store the `crypted` object as above, you'll be storing the password as well.  The goal then is to store only the string content of `crypted` without its instance variables.  I thought that `crypted.to_s` or `String(crypted)` would accomplish this, but neither do.  As a workaround, you can string interpolate it, explicitly pass it to `String#new`, or explicitly remove the instance variable:

```
>> "#{crypted}".instance_variables
=> []
>> String.new(crypted).instance_variables
=> []
>> crypted.send :remove_instance_variable, :@cipher
=> #<EncryptedStrings::SymmetricCipher:0x101192768 @password="password", @algorithm="DES-EDE3-CBC">
>> crypted.instance_variables
=> []
```

Once you have only the string content, you can decrypt it with the password at a later point:

```
>> "R5RVA511Nzw=\n".decrypt(:symmetric, :password => "password")
=> "123"
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Ok. 
But - 'crypted' IS a string, so calling to_s on it just gives you back the same object. 

So - sub question - how would I get a plain string with the same contents as crypted?

Comment: @Tom: I should have tested that before writing it.  I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - so here is an attempt to answer my own question:

- Thanks again Mark for the console code. That led me to this:

You should **use the String.new() method to create a plain string from the crypted** one for external storage:

I think this is kinda strange and a little dangerous, namely that when a string is encrypted, the default behaviour is to include the password in the string.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.8)
>> secret = '123'
=> "123"
>> require 'encrypted_strings'
=> []
>> crypted = secret.encrypt(:symmetric, :password => "password")
=> "R5RVA511Nzw=\n"
>> crypted.instance_variables
=> ["@cipher"]
>> crypted.instance_variable_get("@cipher")
=> #<EncryptedStrings::SymmetricCipher:0x101c58b20 @algorithm="DES-EDE3-CBC", @password="password">
// note that this .to_s only passes back the crypted, since crypted _is_ a string.
>> someString = crypted.to_s 
=> "R5RVA511Nzw=\n"
>> someString.instance_variables
=> ["@cipher"]
>> crypted.instance_variable_get("@cipher")
=> #<EncryptedStrings::SymmetricCipher:0x101c58b20 @algorithm="DES-EDE3-CBC", @password="password">
>> plainString = String.new(crypted)
=> "R5RVA511Nzw=\n"
>> plainString.instance_variables
=> []
>> crypted.class
=> String
>> plainString.decrypt
ArgumentError: Cipher cannot be inferred: must specify it as an argument
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/encrypted_strings-0.3.3/lib/encrypted_strings/extensions/string.rb:98:in `decrypt'
    from (irb):14
>> plainString.decrypt(:symmetric, :password => "password")
=> "123"
```

Comment: This storing of the encryption information in the string made me switch to the encryptor gem. It does not store the passwords, etc with the string.